# Entity Framework - uploading multiple entities with specific validation c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my latest project, I am inserting multiple records from an excel spreadsheet into a database using `entity framework`, I run a loop for adding entries and have put my `saveChanges()` after the loop as I do not want to run it for every row for performance reasons.

I've created a validation by purposely leaving a required field blank in one of the rows during my testing. I would like to be more specific in my error about which line the error comes from so far I have (this code is simplified for brevity, my only concern is finding the line number of EntityValidationErrors) :

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
  lineNumber++;
  try
  {
     row["PK"] = Guid.NewGuid();
     row["EditDateTime"] = DateTime.Now;
     db.dbentry.Add(dbEntry);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    if (lineNumber <= dt.Rows.Count)
    {
      error += "error from line" + lineNumber + " : " + ex.Message + "<br/>";
    }
  }
}
try
{
  db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
  foreach (var e in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
  {
    foreach (var ve in e.ValidationErrors)
    {
      error = error + string.Format("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"", ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks like you're capturing the line number to me. There are a ton of ways in which I think you can tidy this up, but it looks to be doing what you need it to? Although I may be wrong, struggling to interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Entity Validatiion and check the rows for validation while adding them to the model rather than Saving Changes.

```
protected override System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<object, object> items)
{
    if (entityEntry.Entity is Student)
    {
        if (entityEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<string>("StudentName") == "")
        {
            var list = new List<System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbValidationError>();
            list.Add(new System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbValidationError("StudentName", "StudentName is required"));

            return new System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult(entityEntry, list);
        }
    }
    return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
}
```

Code is from http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/validate-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx

**UPDATE:** There is also a simpler way to make it work by using DataAnnotations.

You can mark your model property with an attribute like,

```
[Required]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

And then you can use these lines to validate the model.

```
var user = new User();
var context = new ValidationContext(user, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(user, context, results);

if (!isValid)
{
    foreach (var validationResult in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

This code segment is copied from https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx